# How to use Polyglot.js in my Webpack Project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, polyglot

Trying to use Polyglot for the first time in my Webpack project but keep getting the error that polyglot is not defined. Can I import it from node somewhere? Or do I need to import them local?

```
var polyglot = new Polyglot();

polyglot.extend({
  "hello": "Hello"
});

polyglot.t("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import or require the module before using it.

```js
import Polyglot from 'polyglot';
// const Polyglot = require('polyglot');

const polyglot = new Polyglot();

polyglot.extend({ "hello": "Hello" });

polyglot.t("hello");
```